# CM storm devastator backlight

Tags: macos, keyboard, automator, backlight

Im reposting another users question because I have the same problem but am brand new to the site and I dont have any reputation to answer/comment.I have gotten the keyboard to light up using xcode and stopping it when its lit, but I want to set a key shortcut to use it easier.

OP:

I have a CM Storm Devastator and cannot get the backlight working on Mac. I have followed the instructions below :

Go here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/HID_LED_test_tool/Introduction/Intro.html

Click the little "Download sample code" button

Open the downloaded folder and go to Build / Release

Drag the HID LED test tool file to your Applications folder

Launch the OS X "Automator" program

Choose "Service" document type

Under "Library", click "Utilities", and drag "Run Shell Script" to the blank area / workflow pane.
For "selected service receives" choose "no input" in "any application" (important)
For "pass input" choose "as arguments" (important)
For "shell" choose "/bin/bash"
Paste in this script:

```
/Applications/HID\ LED\ test\ tool & pid=$! sleep 3 kill $pid
```

Click "run" to test. After 3 seconds, your keyboard should remain in a state with num lock and scroll lock enabled, and all the keys should be lit up. Yay! Continue to assign keyboard shortcut to do this.

Click "File" > "Save", "Save service as" : "Devastator LED Lighter"

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services > General > "Devastator 
LED Lighter"

Assign a shortcut. Scroll lock and F keys didn't work for me. I ended up choosing "

The problems I have encountered:

The downloaded file is called "HID_LED_test_tool". This contains 3 files

HID LED test tool-Read Me.txt

HID LED test tool.xcodeproj

main.c

Problem: it does not contain a build/release folder, so I dragged HID LED test tool.xcodeproj into the Applications folder.

I followed all the instructions above renaming the HID LED... file to a simple HID. The problem is that when I run the automator program as indicated above I get the reply xxxxx is a directory. I cannot get around this; I have tried extracting the file within the HID LED test tool folder and then executing the automator with that file name but the exact same thing happens ....

When I attempt to open the project.pbxproj file in Terminal I get the response :

```
Last login: Sat Feb  7 19:34:21 on ttys000
/Applications/HID\ LED\ test\ tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj ; exit;
Zakias-MacBook-Pro:~ zakia$ /Applications/HID\ LED\ test\ tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj ; exit;
/Applications/HID LED test tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: line 1: //: is a directory
/Applications/HID LED test tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: line 3: archiveVersion: command not found
/Applications/HID LED test tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: line 4: classes: command not found
/Applications/HID LED test tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: line 6: objectVersion: command not found
/Applications/HID LED test tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: line 7: objects: command not found
/Applications/HID LED test tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: line 9: /Applications: is a directory
/Applications/HID LED test tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Applications/HID LED test tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: line 10: `       8DD76F770486A8DE00D96B5E /* main.c in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 08FB7796FE84155DC02AAC07 /* main.c */; settings = {ATTRIBUTES = (); }; };'
logout


[Process completed]
```

Comment: you have enough reputation to answer the question directly.

Comment: Do I now? I didnt before because the answers were low quality apparently (they werent helpful at all so i agree)

Comment: it said i needed 10 rep to answer

Comment: ok, lets give you some points then .)